# Using a non-global variable in one function for a separate function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to use the "rx" and "ry" variables in a seperate function (https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV8ln.png) And I cant figure out how to do it, I've tried using rx and ry as parameters for calling the function and even the function itself but It hasn't worked. And I am unable to make it a global variable because it requires many others leading up to it. Ive looked up how to do it and nothing has worked, so I thought I would ask here because there are many experienced coders on here that probably know how and I'm just a noob,

Here's the raw paste, If anyone can help me solve this It would be greatly appreciated :)
http://pastebin.com/UWY8QKbW

Comment: Pass them in - I see you said you tried this, could you post your attempt?

Comment: [functioname]=function(){} is a bit nonsense

Comment: @tymeJV there was nothing to it really, it was just a small bug that the "rx" and "ry" variables fixed but I couldn't define them

Answer (score 0):

Pass them in:

```
PlayerCell.prototype.borderCheck = function(rx, ry) {
```

And call appropriately:

```
this.borderCheck(rx, ry);
```

Comment: I have already tried this, it did not work. Is there any other methods to doing this?

Comment: @Megabyte918 -- But why didn't this work? Aside from declaring globals - no, there isn't an alternative.

Comment: There's a small bug that allows you to go beyond the world's border, using those rx and ry variables fixes that bug. Here's my original code: pastebin.com/Af9qwSYX, the borderCheck function used to be merged with calcMove, so I moved it  to a new function to tidy it up a bit. The problem is, I have to declare rx and ry in calcMove because it requires a whole bunch of other variables which means I can't declare it in borderCheck. I tried what you said, but you can still pass the worlds border. If i remerged borderCheck into calcMove under the rx and ry variables however, it would work.

Comment: I do not know why this is happening, doing what you said SHOULD work but for some reason rx and ry remain undefined (i think, as no error displays in my console)